# Regex: Select multiple lines between to equals word. Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file, something like a yaml, and i try to select in notepad++ all de lines between to word, especially "Application". I try to use regex because the number of lines and the content is dynamic, and I want to select all the individual segments.

This is what I have right now, but this regex select from the first "Application" to the end of file.

```
^Application.*^(?!Application)
```

File example:

```
Other
Application
  uuid='1234567890A'
  label='MyLabel'
  MessageFlow
    uuid='1234567890123B'
    ....
Application
  uuid='1234567890C'
  label='MyLabel'
  MessageFlow
    uuid='1234567890123D'
    ....
Application
  uuid='1234567890E'
  label='MyLabel'
  MessageFlow
    uuid='1234567890123F'
    ....
Application
  uuid='1234567890G'
  label='MyLabel'
  MessageFlow
    uuid='1234567890123H'
```

Groups I want to select:

```
Application
  uuid='1234567890A'
  label='MyLabel'
  MessageFlow
    uuid='1234567890123B'
...
```

Comment: Do you mean you need `(?s)^Application.*?(?=\R+Application|\z)`?

Comment: yea, is like that. Please postit like a repsonse and explain de regex for acepting the response.

Comment: Try this if help?  `^App[\s\S]+(?=app)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you may use is

```
(?s)^Application.*?(?=\R+Application|\z)
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `.` matches line break chars now
- `^` - start of a line
- `Application` - a word
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible till the leftmost occurrence of
- `(?=\R+Application|\z)` - either 1+ line breaks (`\R+`) followed with `Application`, or (`|`)  end of the file (`\z`).